# Visjs timeline edit content item template

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I'd like to be able to edit the content attribute of visjs timeline items in the timeline itself. However, when I use an input as part of a template, it doesn't appear to receive any mouse events; I can't click in it and type anything, and clicking buttons doesn't work, either. Buttons appear to get the mouseover event, though:

```
function test(item) {
  alert('clicked');
}

var options = {  
  minHeight: '100%',
  editable: true,
  moveable: false,
  selectable: false,
  orientation: 'top',
  min: new Date('2015-01-01'),
  max: new Date('2015-12-31'),
  zoomMin: 1000 * 4 * 60 * 24 * 7,
  margin: {
      item: 10,
      axis: 5
    },
  template: function(item) {
    return '<div onClick="test"><input value="click in the middle"></input><button onClick="test">test</button></div>'
  }
};


/* create timeline */

 timeline.on('click', function (properties) {
   var target = properties.event.target;
   if(properties.item) properties.event.target.focus();
 });
```

https://codepen.io/barticula/pen/EpWJKd

**Edit:** Code above CodePen example have been updated to use the click event to focus on the input, but all other normal mouse behavior is missing. Keyboard events appear to function normally.

Answer (score 1):

To get a reaction with a click on a timeline element, you can use the library's own events (see [events](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Events) on doc and this [exemple](http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/interaction/eventListeners.html) on website).

On your example, you could do something like this among other possible solutions in pure javascript including...

```
// Configuration for the Timeline
var options = {  
  minHeight: '100%',
  editable: true,
  moveable: false,
  selectable: false,
  orientation: 'top',
  min: new Date('2015-01-01'),
  max: new Date('2015-12-31'),
  zoomMin: 1000 * 4 * 60 * 24 * 7,
  margin: {
      item: 10,
      axis: 5
    },
  template: function(item) {
    return '<div id="test-div"><input placeholder="hey" type="text" id="inputTest" ><button id="test-button">test</button></div>'
  }
};

// Create a Timeline
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, null, options);
timeline.setGroups(groups);
timeline.setItems(items);

timeline.on('click', function (properties) {
  var target = properties.event.target;
  if(properties.item) alert('click on' + target.id);
});
```

UPDATED

It is difficult to know exactly what you want to do because there are several possible solutions anyway.
Eventually, I propose another snippet below and a [codepen](https://codepen.io/jean2607/pen/EpvmrY) updated.... but will it meet your need, not sure ?

2nd UPDATE (for another work track, see comments)

```
// Configuration for the Timeline
var options = {
    minHeight: '100%',
    editable: true,
    moveable: false,
    selectable: false,
    orientation: 'top',
    margin: {
        item: 10,
        axis: 5
    },
    template: function(item) {
        return '<div><input placeholder="edit me..." type="text"></input><button>send value</button></div>'
    }
};

// Create a Timeline
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, null, options);
timeline.setGroups(groups);
timeline.setItems(items);

timeline.on('click', function(properties) {
    var target = properties.event.target;
    var item = items.get(properties.item);
    console.log(properties.event);
    // if (properties.item && target.tagName === "DIV") focusMethod(target);
    if (properties.item && target.tagName === "INPUT") target.focus();
    if (properties.item && target.tagName === "BUTTON") getInputValue(item, target);
});

focusMethod = function getFocus(target) {
    // target.insertAfter("BUTTON");
    target.firstChild.focus();
}

getInputValue = function getValue(item, target) {
    target.focus();
    var inputValue = (target.parentNode.firstChild.value) ? target.parentNode.firstChild.value : "no value entered ";
    alert("Input value : " + inputValue + " => send by: " + item.content)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated my CodePen example to focus on the input when the item is clicked, but I end up losing all normal mouse behavior: no double-click, click-drag, click in the middle of the text, etc.

Comment: Although the mouse events aren't working, keyboard events do work after .focus() on the input element.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm not able to get focus in your new codepen or enter text in the item's input. What I'd like to do is have the usual mouse actions available in the item's input element: double-click to select a word, click-drag to highlight text, and click anywhere in a string to begin editing. It seems the best I can do is give it focus and then use keyboard events to move around the string. The end result is I want to edit the content value of an item through an input element in the item's template, with the usual mouse capabilities that a user would expect.

Comment: I updated your codepen to make it simpler: https://codepen.io/barticula/pen/gjxZeV

Comment: @Bart Okay ;) I see better what you want to do now. Maybe yet another track that would work well with the timeline template option (really handy).  Working with ids wasn't a good idea here,  in any case it seems to me.
See my new update post (the last one?) and the codepen also updated

Comment: Thank you for taking a look again, @Jean. In the meantime, I'm using semantic-ui to add a popup on the template's input click event. The popup is editable like normal, and I can set the item's content with the new value.

Comment: Yes, I often use the modal bootstrap to edit in this case. I only use an alert generally for a demo. Anyway, there are many "native solutions" to edit the element with the options of the timeline vis.js, but here the idea was interesting.
Just one question before finishing: why vote down when it seems to me that my answers have provided solutions despite everything and nothing wrong either, as far as I know. So a little trouble to understand that?
But good luck anyway!

Comment: It wasn't me who voted you down. It looks like this post has gotten quite a few views in the last week but someone didn't like something. I'd give you an upvote, but I don't have high enough reputation yet.